# Very different font sizes across browsers

Tags: css, html, fonts, css-reset

**Update**: Added simple test example http://jsfiddle.net/7UhrW/1/ using normalize.css.

Chrome/WebKit and Firefox have different rendering engines which render fonts differently, in particular with differing dimensions.  This isn't too surprising, but what's surprising is the magnitude of some of the differences.

I can always tweak individual elements on a page to be more similar, but that's tedious, to say the least.  I've been searching for more systematic solutions, but many resources (e.g. SO answers) simply say "use a reset package."  While I'm sure this fixes a bunch of other things like padding and spacing, it doesn't seem to make any difference for font dimensions.

For instance, if I take the reset package from http://html5reset.org/, I can show pretty big differences (note the layout dimensions shown in the inspectors).  [The images below are actually higher res than shown/resized in this answer - eg in Chrome you can right-click and Open Image in New Tab.]

```
<h1 style="font-size:64px; background-color: #eee;">Article Header</h1>
```

[image]

With Helvetica, Chrome is has the shorter height instead.

```
<h1 style="font-size:64px; background-color: #eee; font-family: Helvetica">Article Header</h1>
```

[image]

Using a [different font](http://fontzone.net/font-details/MyriadPro-Light/), Chrome again renders a much taller font, but additionally the letter spacing goes haywire (probably due to the boldification of the font):

```
<style>

@font-face {
  font-family: "MyriadProRegular";
  src: url("fonts/myriadpro-regular-webfont.eot");
  src: local("?"), url("fonts/myriadpro-regular-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("fonts/myriadpro-regular-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), url("fonts/myriadpro-regular-webfont.svg#webfonteknRmz0m") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal; }

@font-face {
  font-family: "MyriadProLight";
  src: url("fonts/myriadpro-light-webfont.eot");
  src: local("?"), url("fonts/myriadpro-light-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("fonts/myriadpro-light-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), url("fonts/myriadpro-light-webfont.svg#webfont2SBUkD9p") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal; }

@font-face {
  font-family: "MyriadProSemibold";
  src: url("fonts/myriadpro-semibold-webfont.eot");
  src: local("?"), url("fonts/myriadpro-semibold-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("fonts/myriadpro-semibold-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), url("fonts/myriadpro-semibold-webfont.svg#webfontM3ufnW4Z") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal; }

</style>

...

<h1 style="font-size:64px; background-color: #eee; font-family: Helvetica">Article Header</h1>
```

[image]

If we try to sprinkle in the unitless `* { line-height: 1; }`, as suggested by a comment, we see that while it does yield identical heights, the vertical offsets are different, as are other elements on the page:

[image]

I've tried a few resets/normalize packages to no avail. I just wanted to confirm here that this is indeed a fact of life (even omitting the more glaring offenders like IE and mobile) and I'm not missing some super-awesome solution to this mess.

Comment: Have you tried to specify `line-height` for your `BODY` element? Default line heights are different in different browsers.

Comment: @MaratTanalin: Well, things like explicit line-heights are the whole "tedious" approach I was referring to - yes, I can determine an appropriate height for every distinct part of my pages, and indeed that's what I do today to some extent, but I'm wondering if there's a Better Way. A big part of my question was exactly illustrating how different browsers set different line-heights (and thus heights).

Comment: You can use unitless value for `line-height`. For example, `line-height: 1.25`. It's perfectly correct and does not result in any negative consequences.

Comment: I'm with @MaratTanalin - I always set a unitless line-height on the `body` element and sometimes tweak it for specific elements (like a little more in `p` elements and less in `hX` elements). Not sure that helps you though but I've never experienced _this_ much difference in font rendering. Regarding the letter-spacing though, that's odd and annoying.

Comment: @MaratTanalin I see, didn't know about unitless line-height. I just tried this out and it produces more bizarre results - updating my question with a new picture....

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle.net testcase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use unitless `line-height` for `BODY` (or `HTML`) element:

```css
BODY {line-height: 1.25; }
```

Comment: I was hoping this would work but it led to more problems. I updated my question with screenshots/description of trying this out.

Comment: Using Arial and Georgia, results are quite consistent across browsers (Georgia -- 100% identical, Arial -- Firefox, Chrome, IE8 -- 100% identical, in IE9 text is slightly shifted upward, in IE7 -- downward). With MyriadProLight font, text is significantly shifted upward in IE9/IE10 compared with other browsers, but that probably is result of some absent or incorrect baseline data inside font files, so browsers are forced to guess about what position should baseline be at and do it differently.

Comment: Thanks for helping Marat. I'll mark your answer accepted since your hypothesis about baselines sounds plausible, though I checked with fontforge and I didn't see that it was missing a baseline that Arial.ttf has. BTW please consider adding the information in your comment to your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Use Font-sites in pt instead like `font-size:12pt`